# Cutting a string with REGEX

Tags: regex, string, cpu-word

I'm writting a Makefile in order to compile Java programs. It looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

LANG=en

CURRENT_EX = hello.java
RUN_CURRENT_EX = for i in `ls *.class`; do java *$\.class ; done

RM  = rm -f 
TRASH = *~ *.class          

ALL = $(RM) $(THRASH)    && \
      javac    $(CURRENT_EX)    

all:    
    $(ALL)                   && \
    $(RUN_CURRENT_EX)
```

When I compile a Java Program (let's say its name is "hello.java") it works like this. At first, I put in the Linux terminal:

```
$ javac hello.java
```

It yelds a file named "Hello.class", and for executing it I put

```
$ java Hello
```

The issue is that I want to automate this task through a Makefile, and I have a trouble with this line:

```
RUN_CURRENT_EX = for i in `ls *.class`; do java *$\.class ; done
```

where it says "java *$.class". What I want do is to take only the string "Hello" from "Hello.class" filename, but my regex doesn't work:

```
$ make all
Error: Could not find or load main class Hello.class
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

How could I take away the string ".class" from "Hello.class"?

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Why do you start your makefile with `#!/bin/bash`?!?

Comment: @Anony-Mousse Is it not okay? I found it suggested on the Internet, and I thought it was reasonable since I'm using shell scripts.

Comment: It indiates that the file itself is a shell script, but it is a Makefile. That is like renaming a `.doc` file to `.jpg`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should really learn about Makefile syntax. Instead of doing things yourself, `make` actually has a lot of functionality to help you.

As a starter, also remove the incorrect `#!/bin/bash` from your Makefile...

Then learn about `$(wildcard)` for matching files,

Pattern substitution `$(patsubst %.class,%,$(CLASSES))` to strip the `.class` postfix,

and pattern rules, such as

```
%.class: %.java
    javac $<
```

Comment: Hi, I don't have much experience writting Makefiles; I just "learned" reading a few (simple) ones from others and I just started to write mines for compiling my C programs (although from your comment I understand that my Makefile is terrible, I have to say that until now they worked). Of course, I'm still learning, so every suggestion is more than welcome :)

By the way, I don't really understand the pattern susbstitution you have posted :( Where should I put the last piece of code you have written? I tried this:

    #(...)# do java $(Hello.class %.class,%,$(CLASSES)) #etc.#

But nothing.

Comment: Finally I have solved it just doing `java "$(ls *.class | cut -f1 -d. | cat)"`

Comment: Seriously, learn `make`. `$(patsubst, %.class,%,$(wildcard *.class))` or something like that should be the make way of doing this.

Comment: Yes, I can better take your advice and learning to write (serious) makefiles... All this sounded so weird and unknown to me that I have spent so much time for arriving at that "solution". I will google what you say. Thank you :-)